# How to display object of array by its index and property with rezct hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to display items from an array of objects. The items have to be accessed by their index so that they can fit into the menu.

The error I am getting is

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined**

```
function Header() {
    const [menus, fetchMenu] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getMenu = () => {
            MenuService.getMenuCategories().then(response => {
                fetchMenu(response.data.categories)

            }, (error) => {
                const _content =
                    (error.response && error.response.data) ||
                    error.message ||
                    error.toString();
                fetchMenu(_content);
                console.log("inside-header_content", _content)
            }
            ).catch(e => {
                console.log(e);
            });
        };
        getMenu();
    }, []);


    return (
        <>
            <Navbar bg="navbar-light" expand="lg" id="header">
                <Navbar.Brand href="#home"><img src="/ima/_logo.SVG" id="logo" alt="logo" /></Navbar.Brand>
                <Navbar.Brand href="#home"><img src="/ima/s.SVG" id="shout-logo" alt="logo" /></Navbar.Brand>

                <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
                <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">

                    <Nav className="mr-auto" id="navbarItemsContent">
                        <Nav.Link className="text-white" href="/home" id="nav-items">HOME</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link className="text-white" href="/anniversary" id="nav-items">{menus[0].name}</Nav.Link>
                        <NavDropdown title="CONGRATULATIONS" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                            <NavDropdown.Item id="dropdownItem" href="#action/3.1">{menus[1].name}</NavDropdown.Item>
                           <NavDropdown.Item id="dropdownItem" href="#action/3.3">{menus[2].name}</NavDropdown.Item>
                            <NavDropdown.Divider />
                            <NavDropdown.Item id="dropdownItem" className="itemDivided" href="#action/3.4">VIEW ALL</NavDropdown.Item>
                        </NavDropdown>

                    </Nav>


                </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Navbar>
        </>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first time your component renders, `menus` will be an empty array -

```
const [menus, fetchMenu] = useState([]);
```

Since the call to fetch the menu is asyncrhonous, that won't have completed by the time the component renders for the first time. So, when you try and access (e.g.) `menus[1].name` - `menus[1]` is `undefined` (hence your error).

The easiest fix will be to conditionally render the links that depend on `menus` once they've been fetched; something like -

```
<Nav className="mr-auto" id="navbarItemsContent">
<Nav.Link className="text-white" href="/home" id="nav-items">HOME</Nav.Link>
{menus.length > 0 && (
    <>
        <Nav.Link className="text-white" href="/anniversary" id="nav-items">{menus[0].name}</Nav.Link>
        <NavDropdown title="CONGRATULATIONS" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
            <NavDropdown.Item id="dropdownItem" href="#action/3.1">{menus[1].name}</NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Item id="dropdownItem" href="#action/3.3">{menus[2].name}</NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Divider />
            <NavDropdown.Item id="dropdownItem" className="itemDivided" href="#action/3.4">VIEW ALL</NavDropdown.Item>
        </NavDropdown>
    </>
)}
```